# Error in migrating website to sitefinity 5.0

Tags: migration, sitefinity, sitefinity-5

**Error in migrating website to sitefinity 5.0**

I want to migrate the website from the older version to the newer version, For that i am using sitefinity Project manager.
I've hosted my older website to the IIS server and now i am trying to migrate that website to new  sitefinity version 5.0. the older version is 3.7

I  have  downloaded the telerik sitefinity 5.0
 Firstly i  imported the project from the inetpub root folder.
 i browse it and it runs perfectly.
Now for migration i select Actions - > Set SF 3.7 for migration
then i select the project Root folder and the site url and click on the Continue button to migrate.

But it gives me error like this :

```
Installation package for the build version of the specified SF3.7 project is missing.
```

What colud be the proper solution for this?
I am using .net framework 3.5 for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got solution from telerik,

I've to use standard edition to perform migration, while I was using community edition

Answer (score 0):

is your Sitefinity 3.7 site running the latest service pack 4? this is required for migration.

also make sure the 3.7 site is running in IIS and not using the visual studio web server or anything different.

hope this is helpful!

Comment: I am using SF 5.0 SP1 - Community edition for migrating, I am totally newbie to SF, what next step should I take?